# Merging two accounts on a Macbook Pro with OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, user-account

I'm a first time MacBook owner and have recently completed the data transfer from my Windows Laptop to my Mac.

As a result of this, I now have two separate profiles and would like to merge them into one.  Is this possible?

Comment: By profiles, do you mean user accounts? To clarify: do you have more than one Windows profile on your laptop you wish to merge into one user account on the MacBook?

Comment: Why would the copy the data from the migrated account to the one you initially setup not work for you?. No need to do it with Applications, just your data.